# Graph facebook "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use WhatsApp api to be able to send messages but the request seems to be failed
the URL I am trying to access
`https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/MY_WA_PHONE_NUMBER_ID/messages`

Error:

```json
  "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'MY_WA_PHONE_NUMBER_ID' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
 "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
```

It was working that's why I am shocked that it stopped!
any recommendation or advice to track my error
All I know is that it stopped after 1 day (my token is permanent token i took it from the system users)

Comment: In my case, I was using two accounts one for development and one for production because webhook for these two need to be separate. When the wa_phone_id got interchanged I got this error.

Answer (score 0):

The token was invalid (i used a token that it is not responsible for this use case)

Comment: Hey there, I have the same type of error and see your comment, when you say `(i used a token that it is not responsible for this use case)` what do you mean? Is it your auth token that was the issue?

For me the connection to the API seems to work, but I get this error still. Kind of hard to debug. Cheers!